# Authorize attribute ReturnUrl not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

**MVC 4

Razor

C#

Forms.Authentication**

I marked a controller with the `[Authorize]` attribute.  It correctly takes me to the Login page.

In my address bar I see the ReturnUrl as `?ReturnUrl=%2f`

Here is my [HttpPost] method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl)
{
     return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
}
```

However the `ReturnUrl` in this method is null.  My form is correctly pointed to Account/Login as a post.

What am I missing here, shouldn't the ReturnUrl be populated with the %2f?

Comment: that's a post method.  Post methods don't use the URL to obtain data.

Comment: @Jonesy How do I take advantage of the ReturnUrl?  That was something that is done automatically with the [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: They are in no way related.  [Authorize] verifies that a user is logged in.  the `returnUrl` is simply a parameter. Typically if the user tries to access an [Authorize]'d area without logging in, they will be redirected to the login page, with a `returnUrl` parameter.  When they login, they are directed to wherever they were trying to get to

Comment: If you create a fresh MVC application, it should be implemented already, and you can check it out

Comment: @Jonesy This was an empty one.  How do I fake a login to test the returnurl is working?  I tried to remove (string ReturnUrl) but it didn't like that because I have another Login method.  Just want to fake a login so i can move on to the next part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the ReturnUrl data in your form when it's submitted like.

```
@Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = "data" }, FormMethod.Post, new {}){}
```

Comment: I think this is getting me closer, but nots returnUrl is "data" what should i put there to grab the returnurl?

Comment: where you want to redirect the ReturnUrl you pass as parameter in the form it will be taken by the action as your parameter, then you can return it.

Comment: Remember if you dont register a cookie you will always be redirected to the login page.

Comment: So I just leave that as `"data"` and it will know to transform data into whatever page on my site they were originally going to?

Comment: No, data it's a static value, you can save the value where you come from and then redirect to it when you are logged in, take a look at this link I hope It will help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah that helped me see the problem.  The returnUrl was only '/'.  I just needed to set a DefaultUrl to get it going.  Thanks!